# MySQL. Creating an index for "OR" queries

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

I have a table of 200k entries with columns of INT's.  I want to create an index to make queries faster. This is the query I would like to execute: `SELECT A,B,C,D,E FROM table WHERE A=23 and (B=45 or C=43)`. I created the following indexes: `B`, `ACD`, `C`, `ABC`.

With the `EXPLAIN` command I found that MySQL chooses the index `ACD`. So I kept populating the table with more values and I realized that MySQL was switching between the indexes above (not always the same one).

Since there are many inserts, having various indexes will cause performance issues and we can assume that this table is accessed by other queries that require different columns where every index makes sense.

I am aware of the `USE INDEX()`, but I would like to understand if we should trust MySQL to choose the right index.

Comment: What do you mean by "we can assume that this table is accessed by other queries that require different columns where every INDEX makes sense"? Could you give some examples of such queries? Can you also give us the output of a `SHOW INDEXES FROM table` query?

The indexes on A, AB and AC are certainly redundant: these are already covered by the indexes on ACD/ABC, ABC and ACD respectively. You can read about how MySQL handles multi-column indexes at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: Example query: `GET B FROM table WHERE B=12`.
Ok, I can eliminate A, AB, AC (thanks). But it still doesn't explain the reason for using `ACD`. When `D` isn't even in the `WHERE` statement.

Comment: Yes, that's a bit mysterious: the output of a `SHOW INDEXES FROM table` query may help to see why that is happening :)

Comment: SHOW INDEXES test_index_table [Table] => test_index_table, [Non_unique] => 0, [Key_name] => PRIMARY, [Seq_in_index] => 1, [Column_name] => ID, [Collation] => A, [Cardinality] => 100567, [Sub_part] => , [Packed] => , [Null] => , [Index_type] => BTREE, [Comment] =>.

Comment: I think a UNION select is probably the fastest way to solve this, as you've already figured out. You could also experiment with `SELECT A,B,C,D,E FROM table WHERE (A=23 AND B=45) OR (A=23 AND C=43)`. I'm not sure what MySQL will think of that in terms of picking an index. I think, but am not sure, this would probably result in a full table scan...plus there's no real benefits to this approach rather than using UNION, so I'd suggest you simply use UNION instead :)

Comment: 200k rows is pretty minimal to optimize indexes. Do you expect this to grow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of the `OR` in the SQL statement, MySQL is simply getting the first index that includes `A`, which is `ACD`.

I came to the conclusion that the way to solve this issue using an `INDEX` is to make two separate queries. `SELECT A,B,C,D,E FROM table WHERE A=23 AND B=45` which will use the `INDEX ABC` and then `SELECT A,B,C,D,E FROM table WHERE A=23 AND C=43` which will use `INDEX ACD`. This can all be done in one step with `(...) UNION (...)`, which turns out to be quicker and only uses INDEX's.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql can only use the 'left most' part of a composite index. Ie, if your where clause looks like

```
WHERE A=1 AND B=2
```

then MySQL can use an index on `A` or `AB`, but `AB` would be best. `ACB` could not be used as the index is split by another column

With your given WHERE clause, I don't think the MySQL query engine can utilize multiple indexes. I would make an `AB` and `AC` and using FORCE INDEX, see which one is faster.

A three column composite key won't help in this case as you are looking up against A and one other column. This sort of key would help if your query was using `AND` instead of `OR`. An index on `ABC` would be useful for

```
WHERE A=1 AND B=2 AND C=3
```

Comment: Yes, with `AND` it uses the ABC query as expected. Using `A`, `AB`, `AC` would be redundant as mentioned by @Daan in the comment before. From MySQL documentation: "Any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to find rows. `INDEX` on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3)."

Comment: This is a question about OR, not AND.